# Set the latest version as default value in the select dropdown of swagger ui

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, swagger, swagger-ui

I am using swagger **`Swashbuckle.AspNetCore`** latest version with .DotNetCore 2.1 api project which works fine.

Is there a way to set the default selected value with the latest version. Now, I am using *for loop* to get the last value and set it,

```
for (var i = provider.ApiVersionDescriptions.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    var description = provider.ApiVersionDescriptions[i];
    options.SwaggerEndpoint($"/swagger/{description.GroupName}/swagger.json", description.GroupName);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if there is a better way but you could use this:

```cs
foreach ( var description in provider.ApiVersionDescriptions.OrderByDescending(x=>x.ApiVersion.MajorVersion.GetValueOrDefault()) )
{
    options.SwaggerEndpoint($"/swagger/{description.GroupName}/swagger.json", description.GroupName);
}
```

Obviously you would need to add another OrderBy if you had something more than just MajorVersion changes. you could write your own OrderBy Extension if you wanted.

Comment: As i mentioned earlier , without using foreach or for loop

Comment: Re-reading your question; you asked if there was a way and that you were using a for loop. It does not explicitly state that you wanted to not use for or foreach loops. Regardless your code above does not guarantee the correct order (as it just moves backward through the list that is not necessarily ordered with the latest last). Any solution would need to go though the list to determine which version was the latest.